# How to launch exe in the background of scrnsave.scr?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Currently I'm trying to realize it this way:

```
my.exe args && %systemroot%\system32\scrnsave.scr /s
taskkill /F /IM my.exe
```

But the problem is that my.exe is infinite-loop program, and as I found this .bat will never show  scrnsave.scr if I don't quit program myself (or if I swap two commands near &&, it will show scrnsave.scr, and then immediately kill my.exe). So, I need to launch first two strings "at the same time" to make my.exe work in background of scrnsave.scr. How can I realize that?

Comment: You called the batch file same name as the exe.

Comment: @user14797724 what do you mean?